# Replace HTML element with another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm trying to get an `img` element with an id of `origImg` to turn into an `iframe` element with the id `video` when certain keys are pressed. I don't know any javascript, so how can i do this?

Comment: simple...start in google..`replace element javascript` or `replace element jQuery`

Answer (score 4):

1. Bind the keyup event to something that can capture keystrokes, for my example, the `document` captures keystrokes.
2. Then, evaluate which key was pressed. Simply watching jQuery's [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) will handle browser support.
3. Then, use jQuery's [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) to replace an existing HTML element with a new element.

This should be all you need.

**Edit**

If you need multiple characters, you need to set their values to an array and check for the existence, super easy.

```
var accepted = ['13', '8', '9', '40'];

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if($.inArray(e.which, accepted){
        $('#origImg').replaceWith('<iframe id="video"/>');
    }
});
```

Comment: how would i do that for multiple characters?

Comment: @MikeSavi To create custom code for a web page, you may have to actually write and understand code, and also how to debug the problem when things go wrong. Copy/pasting random snippets provided by (helpful) strangers, pressing F5 and hoping is not a good way to go about web development. You're basically asking people here to do your work for you, which is not what this site is intended for.